How to use postgres' ARRAY in django orm
In postgresql, I am able to combine two columns into one into an array like so
SELECT id, ARRAY[address,zip] as address_array FROM user

Is there a way to do this using django's orm? Why? I want to be able to transform it into a dict mapping like
users = dict(User.objects.values("id", "address").all())

Gives me a mapping of:
{
    1: "Address 1",
    2: "Address 2",
    ...
    ...
}

And ultimately I want:
{
    1: ["Address 1", "Zip 1"],
    2: ["Address 2", "Zip 2"],
}

I am looking for a solution using django's orm, not python. I know I can do this by using python code after looping through the queryset.

This is not necessary, we can use:
users = {
    id: (address, zip)
    for id, address, zip in User.objects.values_list('id', 'address', 'zip')
}
That being said, it is probably not a good idea to store data in dictionaries, and using .values_list(…) [Django-doc] is a "primitive obsession" antipattern [django-antipatterns].

Please read the question entirely. If there is not way to do it via the orm then just say so. As I said, I already know how to do it via python loop. There is an actual need for a dictionary mapping and I am not using it to pass to some template or whatever use-case you are used to.

@DonBhrayanSingh: I read the question entirely. dict(...) also performs a loop, as does the queryset when you enumerate over it. In fact by using an array, I would expect it increases the query response payload (by adding extra brackets), as well as Django having now to parse arrays.
